# Footer and Header overlap the content

Tags: css, html, printing, header, fixed

It's been a long time that i'm looking for a solution to print fixed header and footer in multi-page document.
I'm close to make it work as i want but still have some problems :

This is my html code :

```
<div id="header">
    <table>
        <tr>
        </tr>
        ...
    </table>
</div>
<div id="main">
    <table>
        <tr>
            HERE DYNAMIC CONTENT
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
<div id="footer">
   <p>FOOTER</p>
</div>
```

```
html, body {
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  padding-top: 340px;
}
#main {
    width: 100%;
}
#header {
    width: 100%;
    display: block;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
}
#footer {
    width: 100%;
    display: block;
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0;
}
```

When i print this document with chrome, the header of the first page is okey but the footer overlap the last line of #main, and in the second page both header & footer overlap my content.

When i try to add some margin or padding to #main or body it only works in the first page, the problem appears in all the next pages starting from page number 2.

I want to give content a little margin to avoid cutting into the content over all the printed pages.

I have already tried to work with a single table thead tfoot without succes

Thanks for helping me

Comment: I am unable to replicate the issue with the code you provided. The header and the main content overlap but there is only one page and the footer is fine. I could fix the code you have provided but I dont think that would fix the problem you are describing.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, you can duplicate x 50"<tr>HERE DYNAMIC CONTENT</tr>" to make a multipage document

Comment: Still not entirely sure what you mean by multipage as doing that will still leave me with one page.

If you want to stop your header/ footer overlapping the content just remove the position: fixed and they will stay above/ below the main content

Comment: If i remove them it will be only printed on the first page...

Comment: iradev could you elaborate by what you mean by pages? You have only provided code for one page and copy and pasting does not make more pages, it just adds more to that page.